# Is there any point in encrypting identity tokens?

Tags: web-services, rest, encryption, cryptography

I am developing a restful web service and it needs securing. I am doing this using a token system where the client passes a token unique to them via the request header. The service has to be called via HTTPS.

I have seen a few articles which encrypt the token but is there any real benefit to doing this as the token would naturally be encrypted by HTTPS anyway....?

---

After re-reading the above I realise that it is not entirely clear what I meant...

The articles I have seen give the client a pre-encrypted Token which was encrypted with a public key. They then decrypt this token on receipt of the request and check it against the stored unencrypted token. To me it seems that this has no benefit over simply giving the client an unencrypted token and saving on the whole decryption overhead....

Comment: Who is creating the token? The client or the server? A nice approach for signed but unencrytped tokens are [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: In the articles the token is pre-encrypted before being allocated to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a broad question and the answer will depend on your requirements. But, *in most of cases*, you won't need cryptography in your identity tokens.

Identity tokens (used to perform authentication) can be *opaque* (tokens that reveal no details other than the value itself, like a random string) or can be *self-contained* (like JSON Web Tokens).

For more details, see below:

### Random string

A token can be issued by generating a random string and persisting it to a database with an expiration date and with a user identifier associated to it.

### JSON Web Tokens (JWT)

Defined by the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), it's a standard method for representing claims securely between two parties. JWT is a self-contained token and enables you to store a user identifier, an expiration date and whatever you want (but don't store passwords) in a payload, which is a JSON encoded as Base64. The payload can be decoded and read by the client.

With JWT, you can perform *stateless authentication*, that is, you won't need to persist JWT tokens if you don't need to track them. Just check the integrity of the token by verifying its signature on the server side.

Although, by persisting the tokens, you will have the possibility of invalidating and revoking the access of them. To keep the track of JWT tokens, instead of persisting the whole token, you could persist the token identifier (the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim) and some metadata (the user you issued the token for, the expiration date, etc) if you need. To find some great resources to work with JWT, have a look at http://jwt.io.

---

For tokens with cryptography, have a look at JSON Web Encryption (JWE), defined in the [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516). Use JWE when you need confidentiality, so the client will need a key to decrypt the content of the token.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I thought. In my situation there is no need to encrypt the token as they are effectively just a password and are not tied to any time validation etc. It is odd that there are a number of web articles where these tokens are encrypted before handing them to the client as it appears to serve no purpose at all.

Comment: @coolblue2000 In the most common cases, you won't need to encrypt your tokens. Just ensure your are using HTTPS when sending sensitive data over the wire.